# Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement after setting window.location

Tags: javascript, html

im getting this weird error `@app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement` after this line: `if(!window.localStorage.token) return window.location = 'http://localhost:2137/register'`

Is there any other way to change user location, or what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shown is syntactically correct **if** it's in a function. If it's not in a function, `return` is indeed illegal (there's nothing to `return` from). Simply remove the `return` part, which has nothing to do with setting the new location.

If there's code after this `if` that isn't contained in an `else`, you might want to wrap it in an `else` so it isn't run when the `if` condition is true.

For example, if you currently have:

```
if(!window.localStorage.token) return window.location = 'http://localhost:2137/register'
doSomethingElseInstead();
```

...and you don't want `doSomethingElseInstead` to be called if the `if` condition is true, put it in an `else`:

```
if (!window.localStorage.token) {
    window.location = "http://localhost:2137/register";
} else {
    doSomethingElseInstead();
}
```